# get coords of all instances of a subimage

Tags: imagemagick, image-manipulation

This command:
`compare -metric mse -subimage-search image.jpg subimage.jpg null:`

gives me value for given metric and coordinates of an occurence of a subimage.

What if I want coordinates for all the occurences of given subimage?

docs mention `-similarity-threshold` parameter but its non-existent in imagick 6.7

Answer (score 0):

Here's the beginning of an idea:

```
compare -metric mse -subimage-search concat.png subimage.jpg resultimage.png
convert resultimage-1.png resultMap.txt
python extractPoints.py resultMap.txt
```

where extractPoints.py looks like

```
#!/bin/python
import os,re,argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='extract top match pixels from an Imagemagick text file.')
parser.add_argument('infile', type=str, help='infile name')
args = parser.parse_args()

d = {}
with open(args.infile, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        parsed_line = re.match('([0-9]+,[0-9]+): \([0-9]+,[0-9]+\)\s.*graya\(([0-9]+),[0-9]\)', line)
        if not parsed_line:
            continue
        if parsed_line.group(2) in d:
            d[parsed_line.group(2)].append(parsed_line.group(1))
        else:
            d[parsed_line.group(2)]=[parsed_line.group(1)]
    max_pixel_val = (max(d, key=int))
    print(d[str(max_pixel_val)])
```

You may not be using graya intensities, in which case you could modify the regex or parse the initial line where this info is listed.